Flutter - Android: Pixelation problems applying LUT
I'm having trouble applying HALD filters in Flutter. I'm not an expert in this area, so I might just need to adjust some parameters or settings.
I've been trying to use the flutter_image_filters library and my own scripts. Below is an example of what I've tried:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:epishi_android/domain/entities/picked_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HaldFiltersUtils {
  static Future<ByteData> createCubeData(String lutName) async {
    final ByteData assetData = await rootBundle.load(lutName);
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(assetData.buffer), (ui.Image img) {
      completer.complete(img);
    });
    final ui.Image lutImage = await completer.future;

    const int dimension = 64;
    const int pixels = dimension * dimension * dimension;
    const int channels = 4;
    const int memSize = pixels * channels;

    final ByteData? inBitmapData = await lutImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);

    if (inBitmapData == null) {
      throw Exception('Failed to read image data');
    }

    final Uint8List inBuffer = inBitmapData.buffer.asUint8List();

    final Float32List finalBuffer = Float32List(memSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < memSize; i++) {
      finalBuffer[i] = inBuffer[i] / 255.0;
    }

    return finalBuffer.buffer.asByteData();
  }

  static Future<ui.Image> applyLutToImage(PickedImage pickedImage, ByteData lutData, double intensity,
      [bool isThumbnail = false]) async {
    final int newHeight = isThumbnail ? pickedImage.thumbnailHeight : pickedImage.height;
    final int newWidth = isThumbnail ? pickedImage.thumbnailWidth : pickedImage.width;

    final int numPixels = newHeight * newWidth;
    const int channels = 4;
    const int dimension = 64;
    final ByteData byteData = isThumbnail ? pickedImage.thumbnailByteData : pickedImage.byteData;

    final Uint8List inBuffer = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Float32List lutBuffer = lutData.buffer.asFloat32List();

    final Uint8List resultData = Uint8List(numPixels * channels);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels * channels; i += 4) {
      final int r = inBuffer[i];
      final int g = inBuffer[i + 1];
      final int b = inBuffer[i + 2];
      final int a = inBuffer[i + 3];

      final int lutIndex = (b ~/ (256 / dimension)) * dimension * dimension +
          (g ~/ (256 / dimension)) * dimension +
          (r ~/ (256 / dimension));

      final int lutR = (lutBuffer[lutIndex * channels] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
      final int lutG = (lutBuffer[lutIndex * channels + 1] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
      final int lutB = (lutBuffer[lutIndex * channels + 2] * 255).toInt().clamp(0, 255);

      resultData[i] = ((r * (1.0 - intensity)) + (lutR * intensity)).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
      resultData[i + 1] = ((g * (1.0 - intensity)) + (lutG * intensity)).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
      resultData[i + 2] = ((b * (1.0 - intensity)) + (lutB * intensity)).toInt().clamp(0, 255);
      resultData[i + 3] = a; // Alpha channel remains the same
    }

    final ui.ImmutableBuffer buffer = await ui.ImmutableBuffer.fromUint8List(resultData);
    final ui.ImageDescriptor descriptor =
        ui.ImageDescriptor.raw(buffer, width: newWidth, height: newHeight, pixelFormat: ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888);
    final ui.Codec codec = await descriptor.instantiateCodec();
    final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();

    return frameInfo.image;
  }
}


Thank you!
I've been trying to use the flutter_image_filters library and my own scripts
